Почему не работает интернет в эмуляторе андроида на ноутбуке?
Я пользуюсь мобильным интернетом на ноутбуке через хот-спот с телефона, и в общем я купила новый телефон и вставила в него сим-карту, и подключаю с него хот-спот на ноутбук, и интернет во всех эмуляторах андроида попросту не работает, хотя так в общем интернет на ноутбуке, например в браузере работает хорошо. Когда снова вставляю симку в старый телефон и с него подключаю, все нормально работает. В чем причина, и как её решить?
